# What is lane priority?

Tags: league-of-legends, terminology

What exactly is lane priority? This has become a common term in professional League of Legends casting, and I've seen it more on streams of high elo players.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lane priority means, you have priority to leave the lane and help somewhere else by having control over the lane. That means, if you can push the lane into the opponents tower, without them being able to stop it, you have lane control and thus priority.

This gives you several advantages:

- You have the opportunity to make roams and ganks into other lane without losing too much

  - The opponent cannot follow as they are stuck under their tower.
  - You don't lose much farm ,as it takes time until the opponent can push out again
  - It gives your jungler more freedom, as you are able to react faster than your opponent to any encounters with the enemy jungler
  - You have the opportunity to sweep wards or place deep wards without losing anything.

However be careful, if you have lane priority, you also often play quite a bit forward and thus are easier to gank, which is why the jungler often plays around lanes, which have control.

Comment: Adding on to this, you see priority talked about a lot when your jungler wants to take a risk like invading the enemy jungle camps, staking out the jungler/rift scuttler, etc. If you don't have priority, then your jungler has to know that he is on his own for any 1v1s and potential 1v2s that might happen. It's basically saying if you don't have priority, you can't really help your jungler if something happens.

Comment: Is there a reason it's called lane priority and not lane control or lane superiority or something else? Priority strikes me as a very odd choice.

Comment: @Celos As I said in the answer, it's priority to leave the lane. I agree, it's a bit oddly worded. I guess, it stems from priority in the traffic sense. You have priority in traffic, when you are allowed to drive and another person has to wait, e.g. when the traffic lights are green for you, you have priority. In the same fashion, the player who controls the lane, has priority to leave it to help out somewhere else.